# how to go to a new line after getting an input in python?

Tags: python, input, newline

I'm new to python. I just wanna get an input and go to a new line after that

This is how my code looks like,

```
name=input("name :\n")
print(name)
```

When I run this I get,

```
name :
blue
blue
```

What I want is,

```
name :blue

blue
```

Comment: Then why have you put the newline in the input message? Why not `name=input("name :") ; print('\n',name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the newline in the prompt.  You want it after the input has been read.  Try this:

```
name=input("name :")
print()
print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I just wanna get an input and go to a new line after that ..."*

Here is an example

```py
print('\n' + (name := input("name :")))
```

Output

```
name :abc

abc
```

Comment: Upvoting because this answer is the only one-liner -- Which IMHO is the "correct" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would just be something like:

```
name = input("name: ")
print("\n" + name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The '\n' in your code is making the output go on the next line, instead you just go without that, so the input would come inline. Then as you require a empty line before printing the actual output, you just give an empty print statement before printing the name variable.

```
name = input("name: ")
print()
print(name)
```

Hopefully, this solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
name = input("Enter a name: ")
print(f"\n{name}")
```

In the first line of code, you accept a user input which is a name in this case. In the second line of code, you use f-strings, print a new line and then the value entered as name. Your output would be this:

```
Enter a name: Peter

Peter
```

Answer (score -2):

name = input("name: ")
print()
print(name)

name = input("name: ")
print("\n" + name)